# How to handle simultaneous ArcGIS flex API GeometryService calls?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-flex-api, geometry-service

In the code below, when responses come back from the server for the b and c calls, I have the impression that the resposes are randomly given to b and c. The geometry service doesn't know which object is the owner of each response.

Do I need to declare a GemetryService in B and in C?

```
Class A{
    public static const SERVICE:GeometryService = new GeometryService(url);
}

Class B{
    function callService(){
        ...
        SERVICE.buffer(geometries, responseHandler);   
    } 

    function responseHandler(event:GeometryServiceEvent){
        ...
    }
}

Class C{
    function callService(){
        ...
        SERVICE.buffer(geometries, responseHandler);   
    } 

    function responseHandler(event:GeometryServiceEvent){
        ...
    }
}

Class D{
    function method(){
        var c:C = new C();
        c.callService();

        var b:B = new B();
        b.callService();
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure that's true but you can test by passing in a token to the response handler that IDs where the response is coming from.

Comment: I created an instance of the GeometryService in each class. That resolved the problem.